# how to prove that when compile the templates in C++, the compiler create multiple copies and remove the copies when link

Tags: c++, templates, g++

how to prove that when that compile the templates in C++, the compiler generates an instantiation in each compilation unit that uses it, then the linker throws away all but one of them[the commond model];
so there are 2 thing we should prove 
1.  create multiple copies  2.remove the copies when link

we can prove the second one use the code like

```
////head.h
#ifndef _TEMP_H
#define _TEMP_H


#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class Test
{
public:
Test(T i = 0) : val(i) {}

void getId() const
{
    std::cout << typeid(*this).name() << std::endl;
}

void getVal() const
{
    std::cout << "Val: " << val << std::endl;
}
 private:
T val;
};

#endif

//a.cpp
#include "head.h"

Test<int> a(1);

//b.cpp
#include "head.h"

extern Test<int> a;

int main()
{
Test<int> b;

a.getId();
b.getId();

a.getVal();
b.getVal();
return 0;
}
```

compiler: g++ 4.4.1

get the result :

4TestIiE
4TestIiE
Val: 1
Val: 0

So the second one has been proved;

But I can not prove the first one
I google it and have some sugestions as followed
1. use the dump
 yes we can dump the objfile and get the result

but can we write some code to output something to prove it??

Comment: I'm not sure about your initial assumption, but you could try to run `nm` on each object file that should have instantiated your template maybe... ?

Comment: What is your practical programming question? (How will this change how you write code?) There is no requirement that the compiler behave this way. (Some don't.) But it shouldn't affect your code.

Comment: Dump a list of identifiers in the object files (i.e. on Windows use dumpbin) then have the linker generate a map file. Compare the results and then you can make a reasonable assumption if the duplicates were removed.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious yes  i try it.but can we write some code to prove it?

Comment: @CLS _you_ can certainly write some code to prove it.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_TEMP_H`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 is easy. Just create a bunch of different source files and include the template header in each one, and use the template class to produce some output. Then compile each source file separately. Now link them each one by one with a main program that calls it. If you don't get any linker errors but the program generates the output, that proves each compiled object file contained the template code.

P.S. The extra copies might not get eliminated, they may still exist as dead code in the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers definitely *don't* do that. The IBM C++ compiler generates required templates at *link* time and compiles them *then,* in a repeat-until-closure process.

Comment: thank you.i know that is just a way to implement it, so i just want to konw how to prove this situation. The compiler do something in the compile time,but if i want to write some code to prove it, i must get the executable file, but it has been linked.That is the difficut point that i consider,

Comment: Why? What difference does it make? If it bloats the executable you can discover that from the map file. If it doesn't, the only cost you've paid is a little compile time.

Comment: @NeilKirk I do not understand.